# Проблема с подключением requests через proxy

Tags: python, парсер, requests, proxy

Решил сделать наработку которая будет получать бесплатные прокси и валидировать их. Все получилось, прокси есть, но теперь возникла проблема с работой через прокси.
[image: Тест на первом сайте]
[image: Тест на втором сайте]

**Пример работы с этим прокси в коде**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге каждый раз получаю ошибку 104. Подумал может эти прокси заблокированы или еще что, попробовал только что купленный прокси, но и он тоже выдавал ошибку 104.(В примере запрос идет к википедии, но так же пробовал к гуглу и ipinfo.io, все тоже самое)

Comment: Сейчас ошибка выглядит [https://pastebin.com/ZL5QZNt1]